# How to remove an account created by WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Today I noticed that new MVC projects in VS 2012 are using [WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) to handle membership related tasks.

I went to msdn to a quick look at the documentation and was surprised. Lot's of good stuff in there and it will definitely save me a lot of time in future projects.

But one thing got my attention:
It doesn't have a function to "Remove Accounts". Is there a particular reason for that? Should I use the underlying membership provider to remove accounts (and other things such as unlock accounts)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer at MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider%28v=vs.111%29

> In ASP.NET Web Pages sites, you can access the functionality of the SimpleMembershipProvider class by using the Membership property of a web page. You do not (in fact, cannot) initialize a new instance of the SimpleMembershipProvider class...

Comment: Brilliant answer, I am surprised there are so few ups. I merely am calling  Membership.Provider.DeleteUser(this.User.Identity.Name, true); within my controller. The boolean determines if the deletion cascades to related rows.

Answer (score 18):

```
        ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount("username");
        ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteUser("username", true);
```

Comment: You need to add Mebership provider in web.config system.web section to work with WebSecurity:
`<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
      <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>`

Comment: Membership.DeleteUser only was sufficient for me

Answer (score 1):

`((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteAccount("UserName");` //This will remove entry from  **[webpages_Membership]** table

`Roles.RemoveUserFromRole("UserName", "RoleName");` // This will remove from **[webpages_UsersInRoles]** table

`((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).DeleteUser("UserName", true);` // This will remove from **userprofile** table